# Newer tool to trace memory leak in Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I've researched through several posts trying to find a good tool to trace memory leaks, but I have found posts from 2009 and the tools are already deprecated. What tool I can use (if possible, from the android sdk) to find memory leaks and if possible a simple tutorial might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is still relevant](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html). I used this the other week, and it worked quite nicely. Not sure about whether or not it's "deprecated", as it still works and you aren't exactly building it into an app.